# Getting this xampp error message when trying to run only a certain file on local site

Tags: apache, http-status-code-503

I'm using an XAMPP Apache server and every time I go onto this specific page on my local/test site it comes up with this error message:

[503 Service Unavailable error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv5FN.png)

**Things I've done to try and fix the issue**:

- I've tried restarting apache
- I've restarted xampp
- I created a new branch from a fully functioning master branch
- I restarted my pc

Here is what comes out of my error.log file:

```
[Fri Nov 05 13:12:43.393672 2021] [proxy:error] [pid 2632:tid 1860] (OS 10061)No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.  : AH00957: AJP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8009 (127.0.0.1) failed
[Fri Nov 05 13:12:43.395690 2021] [proxy_ajp:error] [pid 2632:tid 1860] [client 127.0.0.1:50520] AH00896: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
```

Let me know if there are any more details that need to be provided.

Comment: why are you trying to connect on port 8009 ?

Comment: @MikeMoy I'm using ports 80 and 443

Comment: no, your attempting to connect to localhost on port 8009

Comment: "AH00957: AJP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8009"

Comment: @MikeMoy Yes, I can read the error log too, I'm attempting to connect to localhost on the ports I mentioned before. At least that's what it says on the control panel.

Comment: @trynahelpyallout Have you made sure you completely restarted the application. Going to processes and completely ending the task for example.

Comment: @CharlieCNX Yeah, I did exactly that.

Comment: ProxyPass on port 8009 ?